# Переход на страницу средствами PHP

Tags: php, html, сервер

Как сделать так, чтобы при наличии у пользователя открытой страницы с ссылкой
cloudstatic.com, она автоматически каждую минуту при наличии открытой вкладки перенаправляла на cloudstatic.com/?update-page (или любую другую)

Comment: PHP заканчивает работу после того, как отдаст страницу. Вам недостаточно средств javascript/тэга <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="N;URL=адрес"> ?

Comment: @iosp Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0):

PHP заканчивает работу после того, как отдаст страницу. Вам недостаточно средств javascript/тэга `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="N;URL=адрес">` ?